# EditText Line appearance

Tags: android-layout, android-edittext

I am using edittext and it's showing a line where I can enter text but I have seen examples of the line having upturned edges (see below). Can't figure out how to do it.

Edit text looks like this:

_____________.

but I want it to look more like this:

|__________________|

Thanks for help.

Comment: That is device and OS specific, but if you want it should look like same in all the devices, then you need to define custom drawables forEditText's

Comment: I've seen both types of lines on my phone. If I use drawables can the line colour depending on its state?

Comment: If you use drawable, the line color wont be changed but if you want that thing also, we can do that according to state.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use layer-list and add custom background to your edit text.
here's a sample.

create a xml file in your drawable folder-> custombg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
   <!-- Border -->
     <item>
       <shape>
          <solid android:color="#f000"></solid>
       </shape>
     </item>
     <!-- Body -->
  <item android:left="2dip"
      android:bottom="2dp"
      android:right="2dp">
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="#ffafafaf"></solid>
    </shape> 
  </item>
</layer-list>
```

in you're edit text do this.

```
         <EditText
            android:id="@+id/edit_text1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/border_line_withradius"
             />
```

Comment: Thanks for guidance, I'll try that out.